# Connection errors with PostGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis, connection

I am trying to import vector data into a managed PostGIS database with QGIS and I get this error:

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

I don't get this error when I import the same data to my localhost PostGIS DB.

We tested Digital Ocean and Upcloud so far and I get the same error message.

What could be the reason?

Edit 01.06.22: We found out that the problem only occurs when we use the wireless internet of our coworking space, so we guess it has to do something with their firewall. When we use other wireless networks outside of the office, everything is fine.

Comment: I often have issues with the SSL settings - changing to "require" or at least "allow" often solves the issue.

Comment: The SSL settings were already set to "require".